# Declare explicit types for a dynamically created class function

Tags: typescript

Say I've got this class:

```
class Foo {
  bar = this.createDynamicFunction((param: string) => {
    return "string" + param;
  });

  baz = this.createDynamicFunction((param: number) => {
    return 1 + param;
  });

  createDynamicFunction(fn: (param: any) => any) {
    return (param) => fn(param);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()
foo.bar('baz') // => barbaz
foo.baz(2) // => 3
```

How do I declare types for the functions `Foo.prototype.bar` and `Foo.prototype.baz`? I want to explicitly say that `bar` and `baz` accept and return `string` and `number` respectively.

I realize that this is a contrived example. For some context, I'm in the final stages of rewriting one of my message queue client libraries and a lot of the class functions are dynamically created. These functions share a lot of functionality, but their inputs/outputs differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) are made for this:

```
class Foo {
  bar = this.createDynamicFunction((param: string) => {
    return "string" + param;
  });

  baz = this.createDynamicFunction((param: number) => {
    return 1 + param;
  });

  createDynamicFunction<Type>(fn: (param: Type) => Type) {
    return (param : Type) => fn(param);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()
//console.log(foo.baz(2)) // => 3
console.log(foo.bar('baz')) // => barbaz
console.log(foo.baz(2)) // => 3
```

You create a `generic` function, for which the type can be anything. And you can define your overall function type based on that **type**

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCMwCdoF5oAXACwEsIA6YHAUzCNoBEBPAOzAFszhYBXNsCJl4bABRiADri4AuaBCI4ybAOYBKAgD4U6DNDpE+ONtABEi5WrPQA1NGk4uAbj0Bfda73YAXgWLkVDT0jKwc3LwCQiLiUjKc8mx8nJi0OJr4Omj6BrRGJtAAjHYO8a4YHl4YwQzM7Fw8-ILCogA8ACoskrRaYgBmbPJxTgnQnd0ZOuO0mtn6hsamw1zQ8tOT0APLnJ7uqG6oqMCiipuI-my0AO5wiGLqqAD0j8dsEPAgtJQg8Kr9iJRfGIAEzqTTPbTQADMRxOHy+Pz+fQB2BwYgA5L50WDoBDMlhcL5YW94d9fv94ICwD4QTi8TooUA)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this!